# SqlSever: Multiple CTE in EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, sp-executesql

```
    DECLARE @sqlString nvarchar(500); SET @sqlString = ';WITH Data_CTE 
        AS
        (
            SELECT pj.ProjectID, pj.ProjectName, pj.ProjectOwner, cs.CustomerName
            FROM Projects as pj
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customers] cs
                ON pj.CustomerId = cs.CustomerID
            WHERE  pj.ProjectOwner =  @ename 
                AND (pj.ProjectStatus = 1 OR pj.ProjectStatus = 0)
        )
        SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_CTE)  AS TotalRows
        FROM Data_CTE
        ORDER BY ProjectName
        OFFSET 0 * 10 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;'


SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ename varchar(100)';
SET @ename = 'mohapam@test.com';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sqlString, @ParmDefinition, @ename = @ename;
```

Here I am trying to fetch no of records based on paging and get total no of count as well. When I am executing above query it show error at syntax *'COU*.

Please suggest any other way to get records with total count.

Comment: Where's your declaration of `@sqlString`? It should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but the error message strongly suggests it's getting cut off.

Comment: Why are you using `sp_executesql` at all? You've tagged dynamic SQL, but that statement isn't dynamic.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, sqlString is NVARCHAR(500);

Comment: @Larnu, I am using sp_executesql to improve performance.

Comment: How does use `sp_executesql` "improve" performance..?

Comment: Nice work on the crystal ball @JeroenMostert :) Manas, if you use `PRINT @sqlString;` notice the value has been truncated. The first parameter for `sp_executesql` is `nvarchar(MAX)`. But, as discussed, it doesn't even need `sp_executesql`.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/

Comment: That comparison is between `EXEC(@SQL)` and `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL` @ManasKumar. That doesn't explain why you're using `sp_executesql` when there's nothing dynamic in your statement. You don't need `sp_executesql`.

Comment: @Larnu, the issue is it was truncating the sqlString. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there's no need for `sp_executesql` here at all. Dynamic SQL is when you have an object that is dynamic (as the name suggests). As a simply example you can't have something like:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'MyTable',
        @Name varchar(50) = 'Jane Smith';

SELECT *
FROM @TableName
WHERE [Name] = @Name;
```

This would return an error stating that the table variable `@TableName` hasn't been declared. Instead you would do the following:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'MyTable',
        @Name varchar(50) = 'Jane Smith';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'WHERE [Name] = @Name;';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@name varchar(50)', @Name;
```

In your statement, however, you have no dynamic objects; we can easily see this as you don't inject any object names into the query.

Also, we can change the subquery `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data_CTE)` to a windowed function, saving an extra can on the tables. This gives a final query below:

```
DECLARE @email varchar(100) = 'mohapam@test.com';

WITH Data_CTE AS
    (SELECT pj.ProjectID,
            pj.ProjectName,
            pj.ProjectOwner,
            cs.CustomerName,
            COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
     FROM Projects pj
          LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customers] cs ON pj.CustomerId = cs.CustomerID
     WHERE pj.ProjectOwner = @ename
       AND (pj.ProjectStatus = 1
         OR pj.ProjectStatus = 0))
SELECT ProjectID,
       ProjectName,
       ProjectOwner,
       CustomerName,
       DC.TotalRows
FROM Data_CTE DC
ORDER BY ProjectName OFFSET 0 * 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

As for *why* you were getting the error you were, if you look at the length of the literal string in your question, it's over 500 characters, yet you stated you defined `@sqlString` as a `varchar(500)`. As a result the value is truncated, and so the SQL doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OVER` clause for getting total count of rows. You don't need to make it complex with `CTE`. Use your query like below.

```
SELECT pj.ProjectID, pj.ProjectName, pj.ProjectOwner, cs.CustomerName, COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows
FROM Projects as pj
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customers] cs
    ON pj.CustomerId = cs.CustomerID
WHERE  pj.ProjectOwner =  @ename 
    AND (pj.ProjectStatus = 1 OR pj.ProjectStatus = 0
ORDER BY pj.ProjectName
OFFSET 0 * 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

[Click here for more details about OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes, that will work. However, it more performance cost as compared to CTE. So I used CTE instead of OVER()

Comment: I'd be very surprised your method (performing a count of the rows defined in the CTE) will be a lower cost. The method you have will require 2 scans of the objects `Customers` and `Projects`; this method won't

Comment: @Larnu, I have tested and found that `COUNT(*)` will give total number of rows which will be returned from `WHERE` condition. `OFFSET` doesn't affect the `COUNT(*)`.